# C# EmguCV stream Mat frames to RTSP Pipeline

Tags: c#, gstreamer, emgucv, libvlc, rtsp-server

I'm doing a `C#` application with some image processing from `RealSense` camera using `EmguCv` and I want to stream images to RTSP pipeline to allow other (multiple) clients to view RTSP stream.

At the moment I have frames as `Mat` objects.
I know that it's possible to create an RTSP server using LibVlc or GStreamer but I don't know what is the best way and how to convert `Mat` frames into a video streaming.
Platform: Windows 10.

**In LibVlc**

How can I write Mat objets to MemoryStream?
Also this constructor o LibVLC doesn't seems to work and running `RTSP` server.

```
var ms = new MemoryStream()
var libVlc = new LibVLC("--sout-rtp-dst=rtsp://:8553/rtsp", "--sout-keep");
var media = new Media(libVlc, new StreamMediaInput(ms));
var player = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

I have also try to write `Mat` objects to `VideoWriter` and I can't create `VideoWriter` because I don't know which codec I have to use. I have try with MJPG, H264, XVID, DIVX ... no one seems to work on my platform.

Maybe it's possible to use GStreamer instead of LibVlc? Do you have any example of that?